# HTML if statements

Tags: html

I'm looking at an HTML page that has the following:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
```

The very last if condition looks a bit weird to me. The nesting of the comments, etc. seems to be off. Is this correct: `<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's correct - if it's not legacy IE it can't understand the conditional comments so it's a syntax fail-over. The `gte IE 9` shows m$ deprecated conditional comments at that browser version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct. It just looks funny as it needs to be for non-IE browsers to ignore it correctly.

If the browser is not IE, it will be interpreted normally. If it's IE, it will not interpet what's between the `if` and `endif`.